# Sending SMS through Gmail using delphi

Tags: delphi, sms, gmail

As you know we can send SMS to any cellphone with the google chat, 
so can we use this function in a delphi program? 
can we send sms with delphi?

Comment: Our company uses SMTP to send SMS messages, not specifically google chat, but it may be worth looking into. We have a service using the Indy `TIdSMTP` and `TIdMessage` to send emails through various email providers with SMTP, and using the same method there's a mechanism to send text messages through SMTP. This is code I've never seen in our huge Delphi system, so I have no examples or details, but just to mention I do believe you can use Indy SMTP to do this.

Comment: I know Yahoo! charges for this type of connection, and I've never used much of Gmail, Hotmail, AOL, etc. Adding to my last comment, I do recall we've only used this SMS/SMTP method using our own exchange server, and that might be server-side blocked on larger email services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used to be able to, but it cost Google too much money to allow 3rd parties to piggyback on their service. So you can't do that using an API anymore: http://news.cnet.com/8301-17939_109-10193024-2.html